# having trouble getting mySQL to run on my xampp

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

So I'm completely new to php and mySQL. I downloaded Xampp to start playing around and hopefully learn. I get up today open the Xampp control panel I hit start on Apache it runs fine. I then hit start on mySQL it immediately stops gives me this in the lower comment part of the control panel.

```
10:48:46  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:48:46  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
10:48:49  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:48:49  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:48:49  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:48:49  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:48:49  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:48:49  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:48:49  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:48:49  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Haven't got clue what I've done wrong don't know where to start to sort the problem? any ideas?

This is what I get in windows event viewer:

error Event ID 100

details:

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  MySQL 

  - EventID 100 

   [ Qualifiers]  49152 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2015-11-10T10:48:48.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 9795 

   Channel Application 

   Computer troypc 

   Security 


- EventData 

   mysqld.exe: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\master-2015@002d11@002d09@002010@003a55@003a29@0020768@0020innodb@003a@0020error@003a@0020fetch@0020of@0020persistent@0020statistics@0020requested@0020for@0020table@0020@0022phpmyadmin@0022@002e@0022pma_usergroups@0022@0020but@0020the@0020required@0020system@0020tables@0020mysql@002einnodb_table_stats@0020and@0020mysql@002ei.info' not found (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")
```

Comment: Did you allow mysql to listen the port in windows firewall?

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: Did you look at the `Windows Event Viewer` MySQL writes errors there as well as its own log, and if the errors are serious they are most likely logged in the Event Viewer

Comment: tell me things I should do guys and I will do it straight away

Comment: I clicked on the mySQL log and the list is very long, I'm guessing I shouldn't post the whole thing on here? what should I be looking for

Comment: The XAMPP dialog basically show the `mysql.log` **Like it says in the messages you posted, LOOK In the Windows Event Viewer** I assume you are running on Windows

Comment: im in the windows event viewer now and what should I be looking at? thanks

Comment: On the left click `Windows Logs` and then in the sub menu click `Application` Then look for messages from `MYSQL` in the central panel with and `Error` in the level column

Comment: i'm getting error Event ID 100 next to mySQL messages

Comment: Click on the line containing an error. Look in the `Details` pane for more information about that lines specific error

Comment: I've just put the details up on my original post really appreciate you helping

Comment: Yuk thats not a very friendly error message is it

Comment: Looks like you have accidentally deleted something from the PMA database? Does that make any sence to you?

Comment: No I haven't done anything major I'm thinking of completely uninstalling and going again. I think that would be best considering I have no work to keep. Is there anywhere you could advise I could read to understand the install process better

Comment: @mikebeckett that is the best idea there. From what it seems either you accidently deleted something OR the installation was erronous to start with. And a reinstall is there the best option to go to.